# ElasticSearch not using all fields (array of strings) for search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-model

I'm just getting started with ES in rails and I encounted something I don't understand:

I have an Artist model (simplified for the example):

```ruby
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

  # simplified to get the idea
  def get_aliases
    ["alias1", "alias2"]
  end

  def as_indexed_json(options = {})
   self.as_json({
    methods: [ :get_aliases, :get_tracks ],
    only: [ :name, :get_aliases],
    include: { 
     get_tracks: { only: :name } },
   })
  end
end
```

My problem is that ES search is not using the get_aliases property to give results: only the 'name' attribute is searched:

I have a dev. database that has a few artists, none of them having the string "Phil" in it, but one has "Phillip" in its alias.
When I try a `Artist.__elasticsearch__.search('phil').count` I get 0 result.

I have tried `Artist.all.__elasticsearch__.import` getting:

```ruby
=> 0
```

and `Artist.__elasticsearch__.refresh_index!`  getting:

```ruby
=> {"_shards"=>{"total"=>10, "successful"=>5, "failed"=>0}}
```

(not sure what the difference is between the 2 commands...), but no luck :/

Is my problem comming from the fact that I use an array of strings as property ? Should I index it differently ?

Any idea/help is welcome !

EDIT:
I'm using
gem 'elasticsearch-rails', '~> 0.1.7'
gem 'elasticsearch-model', '~> 0.1.7'

and ElasticSearch server installed is 1.7.1

Comment: You are just passing the symbols, and not calling the actual method. `:get_aliases` <> `get_aliases`

Comment: OK, didn't see that coming !
I was testing through irb console that's giving the same result in both implementations....
If you want to post an answer, I would accept it, otherwise, I'll approve mine tomorrow...
THANKS !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **Omarvelous** comment, I got it working, the difference being in the as_indexed_json method:

```ruby
def as_indexed_json(options = {})
  self.as_json({
    methods: [ :get_aliases, :get_tracks ],
    only: [ :name, :get_aliases],
    include: { 
     get_tracks: { only: :name } },
   })
end
```

Should be (note the get_aliases NOT a symbol in the 'only' array):

```ruby
def as_indexed_json(options = {})
  self.as_json({
    methods: [ :get_aliases, :get_tracks ],
    only: [ :name, get_aliases],
    include: { 
     get_tracks: { only: :name } },
   })
end
```

Both implementations (the symbols or the actual method) will give you the same result in console:

```ruby
irb(main):016:0> Artist.find(7).as_indexed_json
=> {"name"=>"Mick Jagger", "get_aliases"=>["Michael Philip Jagger"], "get_tracks"=>[]}
```

But in ES, this is quite a different story !

*If anyone has a good link to learn how to request ES through Rails, I'd be grateful ;)*

Thanks again to Omarvelous ;)